# iPhoneとAndroidでP2P通信をする方法について

Tags: swift, ios, android

FireChatのようにアクセスポインタを利用せず、Wi-FiやBluetoothを利用して端末同士で通信を行いたいのですが、どのような技術が使われているのでしょうか？
iPhone同士でしたら、ios7のMultipeer Connectivity Frameworkを利用して通信をすることができるのですが、AndroidとiPhoneで通信をする場合はMultipeer Connectivity Frameworkは利用できないという記事を見ました。
また端末同士ではなく、iPhoneとWi-Fiを搭載したmbedなどでもP2P通信は可能でしょうか？
どういった技術を利用すれば良いか教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 4):

興味があったので軽く調べてみたのですが、underdarkというライブラリを見つけました。
http://underdark.io/

同一のWi-fi下でAndroid-iOSのP2P通信を行うためのライブラリだそうですよ。(あまり詳しくは見てないので間違ってるかもしれませんが)
まぁ、同じWi-fiに繋いでローカルのIPアドレスを参照できれば、通信は出来そうですよね。

Answer (score 0):

同じように、iOS, Android間のP2Pについて調べていたところ、p2pkitというものを見つけました。

http://p2pkit.io/

FAQをよく読んでみると、近接した端末同士で軽い通信はできるようですが、４４０byteまででp2pというわけではなく、サーバを介しているようでした。

http://p2pkit.io/developer/support/faq/